# why is my cookie not saving on the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this block of code and when a user login, it should set the "access_token" cookie to a token, but when i check the browser application cookie, i see nothing and user is unauthenticated.

```
const login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const oneUser = await Users.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    if (!oneUser) {
      return res.status(403).json("No such user in the database");
    }

    const isPassword = await bcryptjs.compare(req.body.password, oneUser.password);

    if (!isPassword) {
      return res.status(500).json("Password is incorrect");
    }

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: oneUser._id,
        isAdmin: oneUser.isAdmin,
      },
      process.env.jwt,
    );

    const { password, ...others } = oneUser._doc;
    res
      .cookie("access_token", token)
      .status(200)
      .json({ ...others });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
};
```

in the routes auth file i call it like so

```
    router.post("/login", login);
```

then in my index.html file, i linked the routes up.

```
    app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
```

Comment: How are you calling this endpoint?

Comment: updated, please check the initial question

Comment: or did you mean somethig else?

Comment: neither of the added codes answers the question asked of you ... how are you calling the endpoint ... i.e. what does the client do

Comment: I'm sorry about that! There is a login page and on click on a butten, i send an axios post request to the endpoint. I get a successful login, but the cookie doesn't save.

Comment: do you use any REST client ? like insomnia/postman or simply curl command ???

Comment: Everything works fine with insomnia :(

Comment: then its saving to browser (check cookies/storage tab in devtools) but your axios is failing to send it because of missing config or CORS issue. set `withCredentials: true` in axios config & use CORS middleware in server.

Comment: someone who encountered the same problem said this. "Heroku won't set cookies for the domain *.herokuapp.com, thus making it impossible to use Netlify or other hostings for your frontend if your app depends on cookies." and this was exact;y what I did. I hosted my frontend on netlify and backend with heroku.